# API Gateway - getting not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header

Tags: aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I've read the other posts on this error but they don't seem to apply to my issue.

I've got an API Gateway setup that has worked in the past.  I'm using Lambda proxy+ methods with a LAMBDA_PROXY integration request.  I've got CORS enabled and I've redeployed multiple times.

I can get an authorization token with Cognito through one of two user pools I've configured, but then every time I try to use Bearer ${AUTHENTICATED_ID_TOKEN} to hit the API I get a 403 and this error message:

not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: Bearer ${AUTHENTICATED_ID_TOKEN}

I've deployed multiple times but nothing changes the outcome.  I suspect I'm missing some kind of header(s) or I'm not deploying right somehow.

[image: API Gateway Resources Setup]

Given that the resources are setup like this, at what level should I "Deploy API"?  I can do it at the top (/), at /api, at {proxy+}, and even OPTIONS and ANY, does it matter?  How should my headers be setup?  This is how I have them now:

[image: CORS setup]

I've seen some folks say (with Terraform) that they have to wipe out their API Gateway and recreate it, but that seems extreme.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen that exact error a few times and it's always because I'm using a URL that the API Gateway doesn't recognise or have a mapping for.

Check the path you're using when making the request. You might be missing a segment or have a typo somewhere.